# define startMonth for jqtimeline plugin in a webmap

Tags: leaflet, plugins, date

I created a webmap with timeline function by using leaflet.js and [jqtimeline plugin](https://github.com/ozeetee/jqtimeline). Do you know a possibility to not just define the startYear but a startMonth with jqtimeline plugin? The reason is that my datasets start in November and the timeline should begin with Nov and not Jan.